# I am having trouble publishing actions with Facebook open graph as the session has expired. How do I fix this?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am having an issue publishing actions with Facebook's open graph.

As soon as I remove the app from my user account, and then re allow it, I get the following error:

```
Error occured
Type: OAuthException
Message: Error validating access token: Session has expired at unix time 1328533200. The current unix time is 1238541149.
```

Interestingly the session expired time code is the same every time I try and publish an action. I am assuming this is the time code I deauthorised the app.

The code I am using is this: [Private Details Removed]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function read() {
  FB.api('/me/nmaespace:read' + 
   '?article=http://domain.com/post.php?id=<?php echo $linkid; ?>&access_token=accesssdfsdfssd',
   'post',
  function(response) {
   var msg = 'Error occured';
   if (!response || response.error) {
    if (response.error) {
     msg += "\n\nType: "+response.error.type+"\n\nMessage: "+response.error.message;
    } alert(msg);
   } else { alert('Post was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);}
  });
 }
</script>
```

What can I do to stop this happening and make my code work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you remove an app, its authentication tokens are revoked, permanently.

You need to request that the user re-authorize and collect the **new** authorization token.

Comment: Okay thank you! How can I collect the new authorisation token if the old has expired? Thanks for your help!

Comment: The same way you got the first one.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll adjust my code and report back with the results.

Comment: I almost got it to work, except I have come across another error as I have posted as a question here: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163949/error-message-100-when-using-facebook-open-graph-api>

Answer (score -2):

An easy fix for this is to request offline permissions, this will give you a long lived token that wont expire. Just add it in your request scope.

Comment: Thank you for your response! When I request offline permissions, will the token still expire when the user removes then re-adds the app?

Comment: yes, if a user removes an app the token is no longer valid, but if you get offline perms and they don't you will never have to ask for perms again.

Comment: This won't fix that situation. This prevents scheduled ends to a session.

Comment: exactly, there is no work around for removal of an app, but this allows you to never have to ask again if they keep it around...

Comment: `offline_access` permission is being [deprecated](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/).